# Why doesn't cairo draw on first iteration of loop?

Tags: c, x11, cairo

I'm working on a library that creates transparent X windows and uses cairo to draw on them. There is an event loop implemented in the main thread, while the drawing operations take place in a separate thread within a loop. The latter looks like this

```
  while (self->_running) {
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    usleep(1000); // Sleep 1 ms
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    if (self->_expiry <= gettime()) {
      draw(self, args_tuple); // All the cairo code is in here
      self->_expiry += interval;
      interval = self->interval;
    }
  }
```

The event loop calls XNextEvent periodically to trap key/button presses only. The window is mapped before the new UI thread is started from the main thread.

When the interval between iterations on the UI thread (the `self->inteval` value above) is large (order of seconds), the window stays transparent on the first iteration of the loop, and it only gets painted on from the second iteration onward. Calling `draw` right before the `while` loop doesn't help, unless there is a pause of some milliseconds in between calls to `draw`. For example, if I put `interval = 25` right before the `while` loop, then the second call to `draw` paints on the window in *most* of the executions of the application implementing this code.

Things that I have tried:

- `cairo_surface_flush` and `XFlush` right after `draw` don't seem to work
- Sending an `Expose` event doesn't seem to help either.

How can I make sure that my loop starts painting on the window from the first iteration?

Comment: (1) This is a bad question that cannot really be answered. There is a bug somewhere in your code, but since you do not produce some self-contained reproducing example, there is not much that one can do. (2) What happens if you puts("I live"); right before/after draw and watch the output? Is draw actually called when you think it is called?

Comment: (3) What do you do when you get an expose event? Are you just ignoring expose events in the main thread?

Comment: the draw operation gets called because I get the debug statement in output. As I explain in the answer, the problem was that I wasn't using the ExposureMask flag in XSelectInput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm missing is the `ExposureMask` flag in the call to `XSelectInput`. With this flag set, one then has to look for `Expose` events in the event loop with the following pattern:

```
  switch (e.type) {
  case Expose:
    if (e.xexpose.count == 0) {
      BaseCanvas__redraw(canvas);
    }
    return;
  }
```

The redraw operation doesn't need to be the full set of draw operations. Having modified the cairo context, it is enough to repaint it on the destination with no more than this

```
void
BaseCanvas__redraw(BaseCanvas * self) {
  cairo_save(self->context);
  cairo_set_operator(self->context, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
  cairo_paint(self->context);
  cairo_restore(self->context);
}
```

Comment: What is the source surface that you are drawing from in your call to cairo_paint? Where is this set? How do you synchronise with the drawing thread to make sure it is not trying to use the cairo context at the same time?

Comment: The fill draw operation is inside a cairo group, and source and destination surfaces should coincide. Since this code is for a Python C extension, synchronisation is ensured by the lock and release of the GIL in the right places.

Answer (score -1):

To me it looks like you are mapping the window and then immediately starting a thread that tries to draw to the window. Thus, if you try to draw before the window manager actually made the window visible, your drawing goes nowhere. If the window manager wins the race and the window actually becomes visible before your draw, the drawing actually works.

Your own answer is not an answer to your question. The question is "why does it stay transparent in the first iteration?" while your answer is (basically) "Don't use threads, just do all drawing in the main loop".
(Of course, handling Expose events is the right thing to do, but that's not what the question asked.)

Comment: You second part is totally wrong. I am still using threads and it works fine.